# Issue with CSS3 gradient in Safari

Tags: css, safari, gradient, linear-gradients

I tried to replicate a starburst effect using CSS3 gradients.  After much fiddling, I figured it out, only to test it in Safari and have it go nuts.  It's like Safari is using 180deg where Chrome would render 270deg or something.

Here's the code: http://codepen.io/syren/pen/Ahkrv

Any input you have would be very helpful.  Thanks in advance!

Update: I noticed that on this tutorial: http://camenischcreative.com/blog/2011-04-26, the same bug occurred in Chrome, but worked in Safari.  I noticed that they used -90deg to 90deg, so I rewrote my -webkit-gradient- prefixed gradients in that range and now it works.  And since Chrome uses linear-gradient, it uses the 180deg to 360deg gradients and it works.

I left the problematic prefixed gradient commented out, to see the problem, uncomment it.

So my problem is solved, but I'm still really curious if anyone else has encountered this problem and why do you think it is?

Comment: I can confirm the issue in latest version of Safari for Win and OSX. Didn't find anything on the issue though :(

Comment: So you almost answered your own question, the issue is 0°. Depending on the coordinate system and implemented we can get different results. This is the type of thing that screams for standardization... and its getting better. Basically you have 0° being straight up in one place, and 0° being to the right in another. I run into this all the time using SASS+Bourbon, i want my gradient to go north and south, and in safari its going east to west... oh well.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but I tried going 0-180, 90-270, 180-360, etc.  It only worked when I went negative.  So it's like one system recognizes only -180deg - 180deg rather than 0 - 360deg.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is in the "overlay" you did not included all vendor specific gradients properties.

> Missing vendor-prefixed CSS gradients for Firefox 3.6+, Old Webkit (Safari 4+, Chrome), Opera 11.1+.

If you want to support those browser too, you have to do something like this:

```
/* FF3.6+ */ background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); 
/* Chrome,Safari4+ */ background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0)));
/* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */ background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); 
/* Opera 11.10+ */ background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); 
/* IE10+ */ background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); 
/* W3C */ background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
```

You are only using **webkit-linear-gradient** and **linear-gradinet**.

Comment: I don't need to support those browsers, and my problem is specifically in how it renders in Safari.

Comment: It is right there, at the second line : Safari4+ ! You have to use ** -webkit-gradient ** too !

Comment: The problem isn't in Safari 4, but in Safari 6.  And it is appearing, just not appearing correctly.